# Split text in single cell into multiple rows with origin cell dependent on filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data dashboard set up with a filtering option for years (2016, 2015, etc.).

My data is provided in a table in the following format:
[Data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njDQq.png)

What i now need to do is to select the correct cell based on the year selected via dropdown on my dashboard (e.g. if the filter is set on 2016, then select cell AB2; if the selected year is 2015, then select cell AC2), split up the comma separated values in this cell and add them as separate rows to my output table like so:
[Output layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ciu7J.png)

The number of comma separated strings in the respective cells can vary, and thus the output table needs to automatically expand based on the number of separate values within the cell.

What I have so far is this code to automatically hide or unhide rows in my table based on whether they are empty or not (thus the table expands automatically based on how many separated values are extracted from the origin cell).

```
Sub HideUnhide()
Dim LEB As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each LEB In Range("D56:D145")
        If LEB.Value = 0 Then
            LEB.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                 Else
            LEB.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next LEB
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share a code that you have so far?

Comment: Hi Aneta,
what i have so far is a sub to automatically hide and unhide rows in my table so that the output table appears to expand automatically depending on which rows are filled (thus dependent on how many separate values are extracted from the table). For the rest of the code, I am unfortunately clueless so far..

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code that should do what you wanted:

- Find the right column, according to a year
- Get the values with the "," as a delimiter from the second row
- Pastes the values in Column D in the last used row + 1

  ```
  Sub Test()
  Dim MyArray() As String
  MyArray() = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="2017", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column), ",")
  For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
      ActiveSheet.Range("D" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = MyArray(i) 'Populate your range
  Next i
  End Sub
  ```